# ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00 when i want compare two times

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I wanna compare two times and i have an error

```
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime
addtime = "18:00"
timeformat = '%H:%M'
now = strftime(timeformat)
print "Time: " + now
checkwhen = datetime.strptime(now, timeformat) - datetime.strptime(addtime, timeformat)
print "Added: "+str(checkwhen)+" ago" 
timecheck = str("00:15")

if (datetime.strptime(str(checkwhen), timeformat) < datetime.strptime(timecheck, timeformat)):
    print "ALERT!!!"
```

Why output from checkwhen is `0:07:00`, i set timeformat to `'%H:%M'`. I think here is my problem, but i dont know have i can fix it

```
error: : unconverted data remains: :00
```

Comment: I get the error "NameError: name 'strftime' is not defined" on your 3rd line.

Comment: You need to import it, and pythonlearn, can you please put the traceback of your error

Comment: And `strptime(str(checkwhen), ...)` just makes no sense. Why in the world would you try to do that in the first place?

Comment: @Charles Duffy 
Because when i dont use it i have an error: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not datetime.timedelta

Comment: To be clear, you don't *have* two times. You have one time, and a timedelta. A timedelta is not a time, and trying to coerce it into one doesn't make sense. Could you explain what you actually intend this code to accomplish?

Comment: @PythonLearn, I'm not asking why you're adding the `str()`. I'm asking why you're using `strptime()` on your delta at all.

Comment: @Charles Duffy
I wanna check checkwhen is added 15 min ago or no. How i can do this?

Comment: Why is "checkwhen" only at HH:MM resolution? If your code runs at 00:10 and you have 23:59, the system has no way of knowing if it's 23:59 the prior day (and so true), or 23:59 the same day (and so false). If you want to be doing this correctly, you **really** should be using actual dates, with days attached to them.

Comment: @Charles Duffy
Because i parse it from other site with this format, eventually i can add 00 sec. You're right my code is shitty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format timedelta object, so you have do that thing manually.

```
timecheck = str("00:15")
checkwhen = ':'.join(str(checkwhen).split(':')[:-1])
if (datetime.strptime(str(checkwhen), timeformat) < datetime.strptime(timecheck, timeformat)):
    print "ALERT!!!"
```

Comment: This code will behave very badly if crossing a midnight boundary.

Comment: `checkwhen` is a timedelta object, then how can this even cross some time(midnight) boundary, if you can provide some example that would be help

Comment: @pramod, it's originally a timedelta, but you're *coercing it into* a datetime object before the comparison -- when it gets out of `strptime` it's no longer a timedelta. That's why what the OP is asking to do makes so little sense, and why I'm so skeptical about providing only a tactical fix that "makes it work" without addressing the conceptual mismatch.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `checkwhen` is the difference of 2 datetime objects, that's why it's an object of `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: @pramod, I know that, of course. So, you have a timedelta that compares two datetimes -- what sense does it make to then convert it back into a datetime and then compare it to a second datetime (both of which are emitted by `strptime`)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not sure about that, I just gave the conversion for timedelta object to `%H:%M`

Comment: And *that's* my objection -- the immediate tactical problem is solved, but the underlying conceptual problem that led to having that tactical problem is not.